# Referencing variables in the config file from a csv file with karate dsl

Tags: karate

I'm trying to have variable names (SubscriberNo in this case) in a csv file that are referring to SubscriberNo I have in the karate-config.js file. I can load the csv data fine this way below:

```
Scenario Outline: using a csv file to load the subscriber base, useful for large data sets
    * def delete = call read('classpath:bss/delSubscriber/delSubscriber.feature') {SubscriberNo:'#(SubscriberNo)'}
    Examples:
    |   read('classpath:bss/newsubscriber/SubscriberBaseData.csv')|
```

But now I dont know how. I've tried to set the SubscriberNo (in the csv to the following but not winning:

```
Subscriber1
#(Subscriber1)
'#(Subscriber1)'
__#(Subscriber1)
```

I'm looking at these but maybe I've missed this in the other docs? https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/dynamic-csv.feature
https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/#csv-files
https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/#karate-configjs
As per the comments, this looks like I'm complicating things referring to a separate file for information

Comment: sorry I simply can't understand your flow. this looks over-complicated in my opinion. this is a case where I think you should follow this process if you need help: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I'm still trying to get used to your philosophy of simple and to the point, I'm actually removing this feature as it is

Comment: no worries. also look at the new `@setup` annotation that makes it easy to pre-process data and once you are in a `Scenario Outline` body - I would just focus on what you do inside the loop and not attempt any more indirection, hope that helps. if you create a simple example flow, I will be more than happy to advise. but with just a piece of the puzzle (like your current question) nothing I can do